# Is there a file GUI file manager that has both directory tree and bookmarks/quick links visible at the same time on sidebar?

Tags: files, filemanager

Thunar, Dolphin, PCManFM, Nautilus, Nemo - I've tested those and it seems that most of them have option to choose between "Places"(that includes bookmarks) or "File Tree" on sidebar.

I'm looking for a file manager that has sidebar with both bookmarks and tree view visible at the same time. Or alternatively with special bookmarks bar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Caja with <F3> extra pane maybe a partial solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[spacefm](https://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/) provides such a feature:

[image]

Of course, you'll have to define bookmarks yourself, only `/home` is predefined.

Install with

```
sudo apt install spacefm            (GTK2-version)
```

or

```
sudo apt install spacefm-gtk3       (GTK3-version)
```

Comment: Thanks this is great.